# C# Download a complete weired HTML page

Tags: c#, html, download, scripting

I'm sorry if this question has allready been answered , but I litterally spent more than two weeks searching the Internet for a solution to my issue. 
Now , I definitly do not perform the best google searches , and it might seem that my question has several effective answers on the Internet. but I really tried every single solution that I found , without any positive results.

What i'm trying to do is simple , and I did it successfully on many websites :

- Navigating to a website using WebBrowser (1).
- Waiting for everything to load properly (document completed event).
- Download the page using DocumentText property (1).

(1) : I also use WebClient from time to time.

And there it is , I get the html page , and I can exploit it anyway I like. The issue is with a particular website that I cannot obtain the full content inspite of using all the different solutions that I found. I suspected the fact that this page might need to load several scripts before getting the full content. Yet again, I read that WebBrowser does run all the necessarry scripts before triggering the " completed " event, so , apparently , that's not the issue. The page that i'm inquiring about is : http://www.coolmod#com/tarjetas-graficas-nvidia-pci-express

I tried , after that the WebBrowser loads the entire page , looking for random elements using GetElementByID property and checking if I get a null result. It appears that when I try getting an element that does not belong to the products list , i'm successful. But , whenever I try to get an element that belongs to the list it self , I always get a null. Which means , the list it self does not load. and I really don't know why. By the way , I do not prevent the WebBrowser. Navigate () from delivering multiple responses , I allow it to give as many feedbacks as possible , and still , the product list does not load , even when I pass the cookies. I Even tried copying all the content of the document and pasting it through the clipboard. Here is a simple example of what I try to do :

```
    private void catalogueDownload()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser wb = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Catalogue_DocumentCompleted);
        wb.Navigate("http://www.coolmod.com/tarjetas-graficas-nvidia-pci-express");
    }
    public void Catalogue_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = sender as System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser;
        string output = wb.DocumentText;
        File.WriteAllText("testing.html", output);
    }
```

Thanks for giving up your time to read all this.

Comment: Sounds like this website is has figured out how to stop people stealing their content, good for them

Comment: That's not the case ! The website belongs to the provider of the company in which i'm working. 
Before starting to devolope my software, I asked permission to use my methos in order to get their content (they're our providers, so they benefit from that), they suggested directly fiving me the CSV file of their catalogue, but the descriptions were in a different language and the images were missing from the file they can provide. I explained my way of getting the Data and they accepted. I'm not trying to do anything illegal or disapproved in here...

Comment: I even contacted one of their ingineers to inquire about my issue. They said that the theme they're using load the page that way (they do not have specific knowledge on how that goes), and they cannot change it unless they change the whole theme, which they wont do..

Answer (score 1):

System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser is a bit outdated, If I were you, I would consider using an external library for that, [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) would be my 1st choice, given it has all the necessary integrations with .NET Framework (and a lot of other languages)

Comment: In what way is the `WebBrowser` class outdated?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. But, do you think Selenium will really do what i'm looking for? because, I allready tried some external libraries, like Agility Pack and NHTMLUnit, none of them did any better than WebBrowser.

Comment: What I usually do, is use Selenium to fetch the raw HTML from pages and then use HTML Agility Pack to do my magic and and extract the data I need.